# IGMP backward compatibility

Tags: igmp

In RFC 2236 (IGMPv2), it is written

> "An IGMPv2 host may be placed on a subnet where the Querier router has
> not yet been upgraded to IGMPv2. The following requirements apply:
>
> The IGMPv1 router will send General Queries with the Max  Response
> Time set to 0. This MUST be interpreted as a value of  100 (10
> seconds).
>
> The IGMPv1 router expects Version 1 Membership Reports in
> response to its Queries, and will not pay attention to Version 2
> Membership Reports. Therefore, a state variable MUST be kept  for each
> interface, describing whether the multicast Querier on  that interface
> is running IGMPv1 or IGMPv2. This variable MUST  be based upon whether
> or not an IGMPv1 query was heard in the  last [Version 1 Router
> Present Timeout] seconds, and MUST NOT be  based upon the type of the
> last Query heard. This state  variable MUST be used to decide what
> type of Membership Reports  to send for unsolicited Membership Reports
> as well as Membership  Reports in response to Queries.
>
> An IGMPv2 host MAY suppress Leave Group messages on a network  where the Querier is
> using IGMPv1.".

My question is how does IGMPv2 host know the value of the "state variable" ?
it is said "This state variable MUST be used to decide what type of Membership Reports to send for unsolicited Membership Reports", so how does an IGMPv2 host know whether to send a v1 report or v2 report ?